# parsing facebook json in rails avoid error occurred while evaluating nil.[]

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-3, jagged-arrays

I am trying to parse a json returned from facebook.
Now my idea is to get as much as detailks as possible from the facebook json.
So I use like ( assume auth is parse json from facebook)

```
education_array = auth['extra']['user_hash']['education']
education_array.each do |edu|
       puts edu['school']['name']
       puts edu['type']
       puts edu['year']['name']
     end
```

Now the problem here is that some people might have added the school name but not the year.
so obviously

> edu['year']['name']
>   will throw error telling "error occurred while evaluating nil.[]" .

How do I avoid this ?

one way which I thought was
           puts edu['year']['name']||""

but this would still throw error in case 'year' itself doesn't exist . (it would avoid error in case 'name' isn't found )

I don't want the following solution :
check if auth['extra'] exists
then check if auth['extra']['user_hash'] exists
then check if auth['extra']['user_hash']['education'] exists
then check if auth['extra']['user_hash']['education']['year']['name']
and so on..

I don't think using exception handling is a good way.

Any good way ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `&&` operator to check for nils.

```
education_array.each do |edu|
  puts edu['school'] && edu['school']['name']
  puts edu['type']
  puts edu['year'] && edu['year']['name']
end
```

By way of example:

```
edu = { 'school' => { 'name' => 'value' } }
edu['school'] && edu['school']['name'] # => 'value'

edu = { 'school' => { } }
edu['school'] && edu['school']['name'] # => nil

edu = { 'school' => { } }
edu['school'] && edu['school']['name'] # => nil
```

Comment: But do you think it is any different in terms of computation ?
I mean even this would inturn internally be an staircase of ifs. isn't it ?

Comment: You could write this with a staircase of `if`s. This is the neatest way to do this, it ain't going to get more 'Ruby' than this.